# Jpeg to Svg and Image Tracing

Tags: java, svg, raster

Currently we have a requirement where we  have an image depicting the blueprint of the mall (red specifies the booked up areas and white specifies the available areas) and the image is available in a raster (JPEG) format.

We would like to drag and drop some icons onto the available areas of the image (in white). There should also be zoom in and zoom out functionality to be given for the above image as well

Since the JPEG has a lossy scaling, zooming after a certain limit can result in a jagged image. One proposed solution is to convert the image to SVG (Scalable Vector graphics).

Going with the expanded form of SVG, it simply tells us that image is:

> s=>scalable (i.e. you can zoom to any level without compromising the quality)
>
> v=>vectorized (i.e co-ordinates are available)

So by simply looking at the XML format of the image, we can predict whether to allow dropping an object at `fill=red` or `fill=white` where red and white are the two colors in the image. This might not be appropriate solution, but I'm just guessing it this way

Now the problems I see with this approach is:

1. Converting an image with some open source tool (InkSpace) - if we trace it with ink-space, which uses portace inside it to trace the image, it can handle only black and white colors.

Note-: Most of the tools comes with some license.

Problem with inkspace is that it embeds the image into the SVG map and does not create the co-ordinates. If you trace it with inkspace, it only creates the outline of the image.

2. Converting it with some online utility - Not recommended in our case, but doing so results in a large size of the SVG image. For a 700 KB file, the SVG generated is about 39 MB, which when opened up on a browser crashes the browser.

Most of the time when the image is converted to an SVG, it becomes way too large a big factor to worry about. There are utilities available like Gzip to compress files, but this is a two way route - first you convert, then you compress.

3. Using `delinate` (which employs a portace and autotrace engines in it) - the quality of the image produced is not good.
4. Using Java code - Again the quality suffers. Java graphics are not fully developed to handle the conversion (size is again way too large)
5. Converting the image to PDF, then to SVG - this also embeds the image into the SVG file, which is useless as no co-ordinates are available

Does anybody got any idea on this ,how to deal with this situation?,Can we handle the drag and drop on raster(jpeg,png...etc) images itself?

Thanks
Dishant Anand

Comment: Depends how complicated the image is. If coords is all you need. Write a html page that displays the jpg and monitors mouse clicks to spit out the coordinates. Then clicked over the vertexes on the image it won't take that long to do.

Comment: Or load the JPEG into Inkscape and trace it manually yourself (rather than using autotrace)

Comment: the problem is when we zoom a jpeg image ,pixel breaks up,my idea is to draw the image on canvas and get the pixel information,but the quality get distorted on image zoom,

well my requirement is the client will be uploading the image to the web-app so we need to provide such a tool that can help the client to convert the image easily.moreover tracing the image with svg only produces the black and white outline which is of no use.

Can you suggest me some opensource/commercial software to convert the image in good quality(jpeg=>svg)